# Refresh token automatically on the backend via middleware

Tags: rest, web-applications, architecture, jwt

When there is information regarding refresh + access token pair there is always the following flow presented in case access token expires:

1. do request / check expiration
2. see the token expires
3. get new access token via auth API
4. retry the request with a new access token

And I don't understand the main idea... Why should we invalidate the initial request, force frontend to wait, request different API, request again, to proceed with the initial request.

**Why backend doesn't refresh an access token automatically if the user is valid and has a valid refresh token in headers? (which can be done e.g. via middleware)**

Is having such middleware is a viable solution or there something I don't see?

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly, you are asking why aren't we sending the refresh token along with the access token to the same endpoint - and if the access token is expired the refresh token will take precedence and access whatever the data is (and preferably return a fresh access token as well) right?

Comment: @MaviDomates, either this way or generate a new access token before accessing endpoint via refresh and then proceed with access again.

Comment: Invalidating the request / waiting until the access token expires is not the standard practice. Same as you've called out in your comment, you can refresh the token without waiting its expiry (ex: 10 minutes before the expiry, refresh asynchronously). Especially for server-to-server authentications, you'd do this through a simple Thread.

This is different for the user authentications though / when you receive the refresh token for the first time, where are you storing it? In some DB / storage / or are you passing it to front-end?

Comment: Here's a question that I've posted with regards to this exact renewal type before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515426/updating-property-of-a-singleton-with-thread-safety